# I can't get the result with g_hash_table_look_up()

Tags: c, linux, hashtable, lookup, glib

I want to use string for key, and find my value, my value mustbe a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>
int main()
{
  GHashTable *hash_list; ///denfine my hashtable
  char str1[32];
  sprintf(str1, "key");
  char str2[32];
  sprintf(str2, "key");
  hash_list = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_direct_equal); ///create my hashtable
  g_hash_table_insert(tcp_stream_list, str1, "ssssssssssssssss"); ///insert my key and value
  char *c = (char*) g_hash_table_lookup(tcp_stream_list, (str2)); ///find my key
  if (c)
  {
    printf("%s\n", c);   ///print the string
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting way to initialise a character array.

Comment: `tcp_stream_list` should be `hash_list` shouldn't it?

Comment: I have been nodified you tried to edit my answer. But the edit was rejected. You might consider **commenting** on my answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

If using characters arrays as keys you have to use [`g_str_equal`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.36/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-str-equal) but [`g_direct_equal`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.36/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-direct-equal) when creating the hash table.

---

If using `g_direct_equal` not the arrays pointed to by the key value are compared but the pointer values themselfs.

So for a hash table using `g_direct_equal` (as per the OP's source) the following line would successfully find the entry inserted before (using `str1`):

```
char * c = (char*) g_hash_table_lookup(hash_list, str1);
```

---

However: Just might like to decide what you want to use as key:

- a pointer value (use `g_direct_equal`)
- the content of a character array (`g_str_equal`)